# How to change event-loop lib in vibed?

Tags: d, event-loop, vibed

I need to change event-loop in vibed. Docs says that "vibe.d has always used `libevent` under the hood by default" and "`libasync` is a cross-platform event loop library written completely in D".

How I can change `libevent` to `libasync`?

I found [example](https://github.com/etcimon/libasync) of dub.json config, but how I can set it in dub.sdl?

upd: it's seems that `versions "libasync"` is working.

Comment: you should put your answer as an answer and accept it yourself if it works

Comment: Adam, I am not still sure that `libasync` now is used. How to check it?

Comment: Check with the `ldd` command on Linux and see what lib it linked if it is dynamic. Otherwise, `dub -v` and inspect what the dmd command line is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use built-in libasync support in vibe-d, add the following to your dub.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vibe-d": ">=0.8.1"
},
"subConfigurations": { 
    "vibe-d": "libasync" 
}
```

If you prefer SDL, your dub.sdl file should contain something like:

```
dependency "vibe-d" version=">=0.8.1"
subConfiguration "vibe-d" "libasync"
```

Comment: Could you give solution for `.sdl`?

Comment: is `subConfiguration` section necessary? Does it's equal to  `versions "libasync"` ?

Comment: I tried with and without `subConfiguration "vibe-d" "libasync"` and got binary of the same size...